# Custom Dialog that look like Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog, navigation-drawer

Straight to problem_ I need to build navigation drawer that navigate from `Left to Right` having multiple `check boxes` and `button`. This drawer will show when user clicks on 'Filters' Button. I have tried  [Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) but its not the solution for my case. I need Just as below_[image: When Click Filters] [image: These Filters will be shown]

Ones user checked & click `go`(Drawer get hide & search the needed).

Then after i think(I am not sure it will solve my problem or not) we can do this by `Customized Dialog having Check boxes which look like Drawer` and then i have tried to build 'Customized Dialog' that `Navigate from Left to Right`. Build below demo [image]

```
 filters.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Dialog callAlert = new Dialog(LandingActivity.this,R.style.CutomDialog);
            //callAlert.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = callAlert.getWindow().getAttributes();
            wmlp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
            callAlert.setContentView(R.layout.call);
            ImageView close = (ImageView)callAlert.findViewById(R.id.close);
            close.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    callAlert.dismiss();                        
                }
            });

            ImageView queryno = (ImageView)callAlert.findViewById(R.id.queryno);
            queryno.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse("tel:+XXXXXXX"));
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            callAlert.show();
        }
    });
```

So, Finally, Is it possible to build a `Customized Dialog` that_

> - is look like above `Filters`?
> - that matches with the `Activity's` heights?
> - which is navigate from `L->R` like `Navigation Drawer` ?

Or have to do something else?

Your help will be appreciated!  Thanks...

Comment: Can you please share the name of the app you're referencing?

Comment: Actually, i am not referring any app that have such functionality. If you find any such app Please share it!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the same navigation drawer and change it's content and open the drawer instead of showing a dialog.

Just have relative layout in for left drawer and have two different layouts in it one for filter and one for dialog.

Now when you click to show dialog set dialog layout visible and and update it's content.

In onCreate of activity:

```
        dialog=(RelativeLayout)  findViewById(R.id.dialog);
        filter=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);
        ImageView close = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.close);
        close.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                drawer.close(Gravity.start);
                dialog.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);  
                filter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                        
            }
        });

        ImageView queryno = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.queryno);
        queryno.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse("tel:+XXXXXXX"));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

And OnClick

```
filters.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

                dialog.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  
                filter.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);  
                drawer.open(Gravity.start);  
    }
});
```

XML

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
    <RelativeLayout  android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_gravity="start">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"       
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="@color/list_background"/>
    <RelativeLayout  android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:visibility="invisible"   android:id="@+id/dialog">
      //---  PUT YOUR DIALOG LAYOUT HERE
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please share any reference?

Comment: Post your drawer layout and R.layout.call layout

Comment: Please refer [This](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/) for drawer layout.

Comment: Thanks Vipul for your Valuable responses! It will defiantly help me. But I have have solve this problem By `Customized Dialog` which navigate from 'Left to Right' and have layout height same as the Parent & Width kept constant(260dp) & having gravity `LEFT`. I`ll definitely try your solution in my spare time!

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible, but instead of creating a dialog you can have your activity with Dialog theme in the Manifest file,
hope this works.
and in activity you can do what ever you wish.